# My systemd service with type as notify doesn't start when the server goes to stand by starts up again

Tags: systemd

The first time I set up my systemd service, it works fine.

However, when I restart the server, the systemd service doesn't start, but it remains on `activating`.

Could someone give any tip of why this is happening?

Unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My App
After=network.service
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu

WorkingDirectory=/opt/app
KillMode=process
PIDFile=/tmp/app%I.pid
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=app%I
Environment=SOCKET=/tmp/thin-%I.socket
ExecStart=/opt/app/bin/start
ExecReload=/opt/app/bin/reload
ExecStop=/opt/app/bin/stop
Restart=always
LimitNOFILE=10240
CPUQuota=90%

[Install]
WantedBy=app.target
```

Logs from `journalctl -xe`:

```
Nov 10 20:51:35 hostname systemd[1]: app@1.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Nov 10 20:51:35 hostname systemd[1]: app@1.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 10 20:51:35 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start My App.
-- Subject: Unit app@1.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit app@1.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Nov 10 20:51:35 hostname systemd[1]: app@1.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 10 20:51:35 hostname systemd[1]: app@1.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit app@1.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Nov 10 20:51:35 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped My App.
-- Subject: Unit app@1.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit app@1.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 10 20:51:35 hostname systemd[1]: Starting My App...
-- Subject: Unit app@1.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit app@1.service has begun starting up.
```

I'm not sure what information I can provide here to help you help me. If I can provide anything, you can ask me in the comments, please.

Comment: Your unit file would be a start. It's status and logs as well.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was happening.

The App needed more time to start, but systemd was always killing it before it had time to start and notify. It only happens when booting because the App takes more time to start when the system is booting.

So I needed to add a larger `TimeoutSec`, then it worked fine.